# Where are passwords saved?

Tags: password, system

This is a weird question to ask, but where are the passwords saved? I mean they must be somewhere for comparing every time. So where are system and network passwords saved?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**System account passwords** can be found in `/etc/shadow`. You need root privileges to read the file. The passwords are hashed with SHA. Additional information can be found on the corresponding [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/shadow.5.html).

**Network or wifi passwords** can be found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. There is a file for each connection with its configuration, also you need `root` privileges to read them but the password isn't encrypted.

Passwords handled by Gnome's password store, the **[Gnome Keyring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)**, are stored in `~/.gnome2/keyrings`. The files are not human readable and should be accessed with Gnome's default password manager Seahorse. On older systems (before precise/12.04) wifi passwords were stored in Gnome Keyring and PINs for Mobile Broadband are still stored there.

Comment: Okay...any means to decrypt them?

And any info about network passwords??

And i would also like to know about windows.. XP/7/8

Comment: i'v update my answer about connection passwords .
about decrypt i think it's hard but if you have privileges you can replace the old `hash` with new one you know its password.

Comment: Oh yeah that can be done but then how to create a sha encryption of a password?

Comment: there is many site can do this :

try that : http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

Comment: Want to add that other passwords that can be managed through the default password manager (seahorse I believe) are stored in `~/.gnome2`

Comment: For windows there is http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/ that might give you the right direction.

Comment: @LiveWireBT i did not get what you are saying about the ~/.gnome2 file !! :o

Comment: @Nirmik he is mean the other passwords and maybe toke for other programs like `Giwber`

open dash and write `passwords and keys` this program will help u to manage these passwords

Comment: Its strange that Ubunu/linux does not ask me the administrator password b4 opening it..!!! It seems like a dangerious thing..!! :o

Comment: there isn't dangerous things there and most passwords are encrypted , if some one change token the application can't connect with site .....

about ssh key you have to enter the old passphrase to change it ...

Comment: but in the passwords and keys application i could directly see the password for the chat account etc..!! :o no encryption!!

Comment: You personal keyring is encrypted and gets unlocked at login through PAM, otherwise you would have to enter all your passwords. BTW I updated the answer.

Comment: IT NOT PROPERLY AUTHORIZE ! seahorse without root can see all passwords there. How bad it is... Because this is Linux?

Comment: Are Network settings that are personal also stored in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections ?